# Unable to upload signature to remote server using `fileTransfer` plugin in ionic but works fine in local server

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, file-transfer, signature

I am using `fileTransfer` plugin to upload signature in my ionic 2 app. To capture signature I am using `angular2-signaturepad`.

```
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'file',
    fileName: 'Order_'+this.order_data.order_id+"_"+this.order_data.order_type+".png",
    headers: {},
};
fileTransfer.upload(this.signaturePad.toDataURL(), 
this.api+'php/wd_upload.php?location=signs', options)
    .then((data) => {
      // success
    }, (err) => {
      // error
    });
```

The above code works fine in local server, and signature is uploaded successfully. But when I try to change this api to refer remote server. This file transfer failed with following error

```
body: "<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>"
code: 1
exception: "http://<remote_server>/php/wd_upload.php?location=signs"
http_status: 406
source: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAADICAYAAABS39xVAAAYsElEQVR4Xu2dXXBVVZbHd4QmCfMyScq ...."
target: "http://<remote_server>/php/wd_upload.php?location=signs"
```

Please solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything worked fine when I replaced `option` as follow

```
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'file',
    fileName: 'Order_'+this.order_data.order_id+"_"+this.order_data.order_type+".png",
    httpMethod : 'POST',
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    chunkedMode: false,
    headers : {"Accept": "image/png"}
  };
```